# .join() gives back list as a result in python

Tags: python, string, list, integer

Could someone, please, explain why .join() behaves in the following way:

```
input = [1, 0, 5, 3, 4, 12, 19]
a = " ".join(str(input))
print(a)
```

And the result is:

```
[ 1 ,   0 ,   5 ,   3 ,   4 ,   1 2 ,   1 9 ]
```

Not only is there still a list, but also an additional space.
How come?
When I use map() it works:

```
a = " ".join(list(map(str, input)))
```

But I would like to know what is wrong with the .join method I'm using.

Comment: There is no list and there was no list as it concerns `join()`. Before you converted the list to a string (that looks like a list when printed), and you get the a string back with the characters separated by spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str(input)` returns one string `'[1, 0, 5, 3, 4, 12, 19]'`, so then `join` uses each character of the string as input (a string is an iterable, like a list), effectively adding a space between each.

The effect is more visible if we join with a `-`: `'[-1-,- -0-,- -5-,- -3-,- -4-,- -1-2-,- -1-9-]'`

In contrast, `list(map(str, input))` converts each number to string, giving a list of strings (`['1', '0', '5', '3', '4', '12', '19']`), which `join` then converts to `'1 0 5 3 4 12 19'`

Comment: To add, the additional space is because you are joining each "character" in the string with a space

Comment: @Mortz yes, I just updated the answer to clarify on that ;)

Answer (score 1):

See @mozway's answer to understand `.join()`'s behavior.

To get what you want (using join), you should try this:

```
input = [1, 0, 5, 3, 4, 12, 19]
a = " ".join([str(i) for i in input])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
1 0 5 3 4 12 19
```

Comment: Btw, `" ".join([str(i) for i in input])` is (surprisingly) better than `" ".join(str(i) for i in input)` [due to the internal behavior of `join`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-in-python) ;)

Comment: @mozway Huh, interesting. Usually generators are better! Updated the post.

Comment: Why do you think `map` is better? I think `map` vs a generator-comprehension is only a matter of style here

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-in-python) is a reference for the list vs generator speed in `join`. (I'll update my first comment and delete here)